# Ctrl + C isn't stopping my Vite+React server on VS Code

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

I'm building website using React and Vite by following a youtube tutorial. That guy is stopping the React server, just hitting the Ctrl + C but when I try to do the same, the command seems to be not working. So how should I stop the server, just using the VS Code terminal?

I need to stop the React server, just using the terminal in VS Code and at the same time I can be able to restart the server again by just hitting 'npm start'

Comment: Vite dev server shows at the beginning that pressing the letter Q quits.  If you are doing Vite preview,  then Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running a node.js server, place this in your server.js file:

```
process.on("SIGINT", function () {
  console.log("\nGracefully shutting down from SIGINT (Ctrl-C)");
  // some other closing procedures go here
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Press `q` to exit (you can find it among other options when you press `h`).

Answer (score 0):

Press q + `enter` to quit the Vite+React Project.

You can refer the below screenshot :

[image]